# How to fix name conflict in unity engine for android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

[How to fix this? Player settings button given there dont take any action. After pressing ok it opens 'This pc' automatically. For android.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb7TB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Its a bundle identifier problem just follow these steps and then perform BUILD